# Do we need to lock mutex around std::map<K, V>::find function?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, mutex

Here we are:

```
template<typename TK, typename TV>
class MetaAssociator
{
public:

   void Set(TK key, TV const & value)
   {
      boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock(m_Mutex);
      m_Map[key] = value;
   }

   TV Get(TK key) const
   {
      boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock(m_Mutex); // this one
      std::map<TK,TV>::const_iterator iter = m_Map.find(key);
      return iter == m_Map.end() ? TV() : iter->second;
   }

private:
   mutable boost::mutex m_Mutex;
   std::map<TK,TV> m_Map;
};
```

Do we really need to lock mutex in the get function? We are only providing read only access. What if we do not?

Comment: so what do you think happens if, after writing the first 8 bits in your setter, you try to read the value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, we need it.

Let's suppose 2 threads A and B:

- The thread A is setting the value.
- The thread B is reading this value at the same time.

Data races conditions can be produced here, including segmentation fault (thread B is trying to use an object which doesn't exist anymore).

We can use a mutex for protect these sections (like in your example). Another option is to use a [read and write lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock). The advantage of a read-write lock is that allows concurrent read-access.

Comment: Does find by itself need a mutex? can I use find and only if itr == end, use mutex? assume that if the cell exist we will not write.

Comment: @AssafLivne you could check that and inmediately change the data in other thread. That's not solution.

Answer (score 3):

Simultaneous access to the same object from two execution threads, when at least on access is a modification, is a classic example of undefined behavior, which in this case is a data race.

Because of that, unless you have other ways to guarantee that `Set` will never be called simultaneously with `Red` (though synchronization placed in other parts of the program) you do need a synchronization primitive there. However, as other commentators suggest, `std::shared_mutex` might be more appropriate for read/write type of lock.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is two-fold.

1. Locking itself: yes, it's required due potential reorderings, partial read/writes and other parallel things
2. Data safety: you got a result via Get(), then deleted that entry from the map (guarded the same way as getter and setter), then trying to access the result stored locally. What should happen then? For instance, in case TV is just a raw pointer to something, you're in trouble with dead link in your hands...

Answer (score 1):

Because some process can be writing when the other one is reading.

Check the classical "Readers Writers Problem"